# PHP with DataTables gives an Invalid JSON response due to quotes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, datatables

I encountered a problem fetching my data from my database and display it via DataTables. I found out that most of my data has single and double quotes and other special characters. I tried every escaping functions in PHP but it didn't work. **addslashes** only retrieves 59 data out of 40,000 data. So far, i have this code:

**PHP:**

```
$query = mysqli_query($new_conn, "SELECT * FROM bill_of_materials");

$table = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


    $table.= '{
        "allotment_code":"'.$row['allotment_code'].'",
        "activity":"'.$row['activity'].'",
        "category_name":"'.addslashes($row['category_name']).'",
        "description":"'.addslashes($row['description']).'"
    },';
}


$table = substr($table,0, strlen($table) - 1);

echo '{"data":['.$table.']}';


**jQuery data tables:**

    $(function() {

        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "pageLength": 50,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "ajax": base_url('ajax/ajaxGetBOM.php'),
            "columns":[
                {mData: "allotment_code"},
                {mData: "activity"},
                {mData: "category_name"},
                {mData: "description"}
            ],
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    })

    function base_url(path) {

        var url = 'https://192.168.3.254/'+path;
        return url;
    }
```

The error is like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that your data isn't sent to the table in valid JSON? In the past, I've used PHP's [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and that seems to deal with any issues nicely. Perhaps give that a go rather than build your own JSON string from your query?

Comment: I'll try that. thanks for the response.

Comment: `addslashes()` is a PHP function that has very little utility in general, but it's particularly unsuitable for the purpose of building JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to properly encode your response using JSON format.

```
$query = mysqli_query($new_conn, "SELECT * FROM bill_of_materials");

$data = array();   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $data[] = array(
      "allotment_code" => $row["allotment_code"],
      "activity" => $row["activity"],
      "category_name" => $row["category_name"],
      "description" => $row["description"]
   );
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array("data" => $data));
```